# Как вывести из таблицы только строки, которых нет в другой таблице?

Tags: sql, oracle

Предположим, есть таблица `t1`:

```
id name
-- ----------
 1 Владимир
 2 Татьяна
 3 Александр
 4 Борис
```

И есть ее частичный дубликат t2:

```
id name
-- ----------
 1 Владимир
 2 Татьяна
```

Как вывести из таблицы `t1` строки, которых нет в таблице `t2`?

Можно ли это сделать без подзапросов?

Answer (score 2):

Вот как звучит вопрос - *вывести из таблицы t1 строки, которых нет в таблице t2*, так и пишите (только по английски):

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from t2 
    where t2.id = t1.id)
```

---

Доп. вопрос: *Можно ли это сделать без подзапросов?*. Можно, но вряд ли нужно, т.к. скорее никаких преимуществ это не даст:

```
select t1.*
from t1
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
NATURAL LEFT JOIN t2
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: но в t2 нет записей с id = null

Comment: @Denis Поправил.